# How to write a list of names from a .txt in front of a numbers list in shell?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a namelist.txt doc like:

```
Name:Mary Miller | Date of birth:03-01-1935 
Name:Harry Jonhson | Date of birth:06-08-1955
```

And I have to write a document like:

```
ID;name
```

where ID is :

```
nut = $(awk '{print (NR)}' namelist.txt)
for i  in $nut
do
echo -n $(($i+10000))
echo ":"
done
```

but now I can't add the names in front of the ":". And how would i put that on a new doc .txt? Using > ?

Expected output:

```
10001:Mary Miller
10002:Harry Jonhson
```

Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using all awk:

```
$ awk -F" [|] " -v c=10001 -v OFS=":" '{split($1,a,/:/);print c++,a[2]}' file
```

Output:

```
10001:Mary Miller
10002:Harry Jonhson
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F" [|] " -v c=10001 -v OFS=":" '{  # some parameters
    split($1,a,/:/)                       # split at : to get the name
    print c++,a[2]                        # output id and name
}' file
```

To write the output to another file:

```
$ awk ... file > another_file
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F'|' -v c=10000 '{sub(/^Name/,++c); print $1}' file

10001:Mary Miller
10002:Harry Jonhson
```

separate the record at the pipe sign, replace "Name" with pre incremented counter with starts at 10000 value.  Print only the first field.

PS.  Jonhson is most likely a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F':| *[|]' -v OFS=':' -v c=10000 '{print ++c, $2}' file
10001:Mary Miller
10002:Harry Jonhson
```

or if you want a header line printed too:

```
$ awk -F':| *[|]' -v OFS=':' -v c=10000 'NR==1{print "ID", $1} {print ++c, $2}' file
ID:Name
10001:Mary Miller
10002:Harry Jonhson
```